# Accessing files stored in Swift object from inside a OpenStack VM instance

Tags: openstack-swift

I have uploaded some zip archive files to Swift object store and marked them as public. I want to download these files from inside a VM instance. I am running CentOS 7 in the VM.

Is it possible to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed `python-swiftclient` and `python-openstackclient` using `pip` and setup OpenStack API access environment inside the VM instance using the `OpenStack RC` file downloaded from the Horizon console.

After that, running the command `swift download _container_name_` (replace `_container_name_` with the container you need to access) downloaded all the files associated with the container to the VM instance's file system.

Wish there was a simpler way like mounting a remote file system. But for that I should have used a block store instead of an object store.